# How should I specify the constness of a constructor argument to a pointer member

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

Basically I want to have a simple class that wrap a pointer (i.e. has a pointer member) and I don't know how to specify the constness of the constructor arguments. If I do this

```
class A {
public:
    A(int *d) : data(d) {}

private:
    int *data;
};
```

Then I can't do this

```
void func(const int *param) {
    const A aInstance(param);
}
```

because the constructor doesn't take a const pointer.

I want to be able to construct const objects and take const pointers to do it, but I *also want to be able to construct non-const objects that modify the pointer*. How do I specify this class so that I can modify `*data` when it's relevant, but I can construct a const object what that is relevant?

Comment: Remove the const via cast in func? Seems to be the most sane approach. There is no "const constructur". Could turn the func into a static "createconst" method for better encapsulation

Comment: You may need two different classes `A` and `const_A`, just as `std::list<int>::iterator` and `std::list<int>::const_iterator` are different classes.

Comment: @aschepler would that make having a const `A` would be meaningless? In the case of the function example, that would still be illegal, right?

Comment: Meta answer: Make up your mind: Does `A` need to modify the pointee or not? If both somehow holds true (`A` must be constructable from `const*`, but also sometimes modify the pointee), `A` probably tries to do to many things at once and should really be two classes.

Comment: Have multiple constructors?

Comment: The whole point of specifying const on a variable is that the type is not responsible for knowing if it will be modified, the *caller* is. `A` modifies `data`. No question. But `const A` does not modify `data`. In fact I've already ensured this with const methods. But that's not really the question. The class already does what I want it to. The question is how to construct a const object from const params. Is it impossible?

Comment: You could try making the type of the pointee a class template parameter. Then you could instantiate it as A<int>(param) or A<const int>(param). Depending on context this may also make the class more generally  useful. This would produce distinct classes for 'Foo' and 'const Foo' though, so I'm not sure if it meets your needs.

Comment: Hmm, @JohnAuld that's an interesting idea. I wonder if that breaks any other const correctness...

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor should take a pointer which points to a constant object:

```
A(const int *d) : data(d) {}
```

Comment: In the case of `A` in my question, that's invalid. The compiler complains that I'm trying to initialize an `int*` with a `const int*` and suggest I cast it

Comment: Ah, right.  The data member should const int *data as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a key misconception here: The compiler is warning you that you're passing a pointer to a `const int` into an object which might try to change the `int`'s value. Declaring `const A` doesn't fix that problem because, while `data` cannot change, the thing that `data` points to still can.

The solution you need has already been provided by others in the comments:

1. If `A` doesn't need to modify `*data` then you should declare it's member variable as `const int *data`.
2. Otherwise you'll need to provide two versions: `A` and `const_A`. You could type out two separate definitions or use templates so you only have to type it out once.
3. If you *know* that your usage is safe and you want to live dangerously then you could use `const_cast` to remove the constness and thwart the compiler's warning.

Comment: That's not the misconception. I know the difference between `const int *` and `int * const`. I could gladly place `int * const` in my constructor, but that won't allow me to construct a `const A` object, nor will it let me take a `const int *` argument into the constructor. The fundamental concept here is that a `const A` _does_ promise not to modify the _data pointed to by_ `*data` (if I am diligent in programming the class A), and therefor constructing a `const A` does something different than construct an `A`.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer that seems to satisfactorily maybe answer the question is a comment from @JohnAuld who suggested I template the class thusly

```
template< typename data_t >
class A
{
    public:
    A(data_t *data) : d(data) {}

    private:
    data_t *d;
};
```

In theory this would work well to construct a `const`able object, and it even lets me create const and non-const methods for which compilation will fail if I try to assign something to the data pointed to by `d` for const objects. That's all fine and dandy. It even let's me do what I wanted:

```
void doSomething(const int *somePointer) {
    A<const int> a(somePointer);
}
```

However, where it fails is to use const specifiers on the class. If I wanted to pass the subsequent const object to another function, it would fail:

```
void doSomethingToAnA(const A<int> &a);
void doSomethingToIntPointer(const int *aPointer) {
    const A<int> aInstance(aPointer);
    doSomethingToAnA(aInstance);//womp womp
}
```

basically `const A<int> != A<const int>`